# "No device connected" for Wacom One tablet

Tags: macos, wacom

I have a *Wacom One* attached via mini-USB to my macbook pro 2020 running Catalina.  This device is still supported under Catalina / macOS 10.15:

[image]

The Wacom driver was successfully installed and can be seen as running via *Activity Monitor* :

[image]

The various settings were also set properly:

*Settings | Input Monitoring*

[image]

*Settings | Security & Privacy | Accessibility*

[image]

However the *Wacom Desktop Center* reports that the tablet is not connected:

[image]

What else should I check/do ?

**Update** I rebooted with the Wacom One connected but still get the "No Device Connected" fro the Desktop Center.

Comment: idk about modern Wacoms, but the old ones had to be connected before boot to register.

Comment: @Tetsujin  `Wacom One` is not a modern one ;)  I'll try rebooting based on your suggestion

Comment: When you say “the Wacom driver” does that driver a) support your tablet b) support your OS version?

Comment: Ah, OK… bearing in mind mine is the first Intuos with USB, they all seem 'new' to me ;]

Comment: @bmike I updated the question with screenshot showing proper driver support for 10.13+ (10.13 -> 11.0) for the Wacom One.

Comment: @Tetsujin fyi I rebooted and no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well.   I plugged in my `iPhone` and the `Wacome One` woke up!

[image]

What does the first action have to do with the second?  Apparently the "tremendous weight" of the usb-c cable for the iPhone - which was a bit entangled with the mini-USB cable to the Wacom -  was just enough to put the Wacom connector out of sorts. Jiggling the cable to the iPhone apparently undid that "flakey cable" issue.

So the only potential value now to this question is to confirm *YES the Wacom One is  working (surprisingly I might add) with macOS Catalina*.

**Update** Apparently there is a specific power cord for Wacom that has a few parts including hdmi, power cable, mini-usb.  I must have tossed it / lost it some time ago.  So this device is a small-ish brick now.